# How to scale and resize Path control in xamarin form?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, figma

I draw a frame in Figma and try to implement it in xamarin form but I am unable to scale it across different device size. I try to resize it without using `Aspect="Uniform"` but it does not work.

1. Figma frame
   I used Iphone frame in Figma to draw the shape.

[image]

2. Xaml design
   I copied the Path of the shape from Figma to xaml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="Mobile.WelcomePage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
<Path Aspect="Uniform" Data="M51.25 307C51.25 309.12 52.2277 311.013 53.757 312.25H25C11.6071 312.25 0.75 301.393 0.75 288V25C0.75 11.6071 11.6071 0.75 25 0.75H359C372.393 0.75 383.25 11.6071 383.25 25V288C383.25 301.393 372.393 312.25 359 312.25H330.243C331.772 311.013 332.75 309.12 332.75 307V263.107C332.75 259.379 329.728 256.357 326 256.357H58C54.2721 256.357 51.25 259.379 51.25 263.107V307Z" Fill="#1098FC" Stroke="1.5"/>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

3. iPhone 7 result
   On the image below, the shape goes beyond the screen size

[image]

4. Iphone 13 result
   On iPhone 13 it wells called but I am unable to resize it

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/shapes/path-transforms#scale-transform

Comment: What if you added HorizontalOptions="Fill"
    VerticalOptions="Fill" to the path control. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-shapes-and-paths/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Aspect="Uniform"` is supposed to work  and it actually works perfectly based on my test .

[image]

I suggest you update `Xamarin.Forms` package to the latest  and try again .

Comment: After update I fixed the issue but I realized `Aspect=Uniform` places the control in the center if the device.

Comment: Change parent layout from `Grid` to `StackLayout ` should be able to solve the problem .